# RegExp returning false when it shows true on online tester

Tags: javascript

```
var str = "+9665612345678";
var patt = new RegExp("/\+9665\d{8}/g");
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res);
```

Above code returns false while it shows true on online tests

https://regex101.com/r/jb6bwS/1

Why is it returning false when it should be true?

Comment: that is not how you use new RegExp

Comment: theres no need to use the constructor form here: `/\+9665\d{8}/g` is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of new Reg Exp is wrong.

It would look like

```
var patt = new RegExp("\\+9665\\d{8}",'g');
```

I would skip RegExp and just do

```
var patt = /\+9665\d{8}/g;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @spascarello. Question though, without RegExp test function would give error wouldnt it? or should i use match with your second approach?